# How to use pointer to string in cpp?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am studying pointers in C++. I have studied call by value and call by reference concept. I am trying to create a function to reverse a string which accepts a pointer to string and the size of string. The code is as follow

```
void reverse(string* str, int size)
{

    int start = 0;
    int end = size - 1;

    while(start < end)
    {
        swap(*str[start++], *str[end--]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    
    string str = "Something";
    
    reverse(&str, str.length());

    cout << "Reversed string: " << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::string’ {aka
‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’})
   12 |         swap(*str[start++], *str[end--]);
```

I don't want to use the character array, is there way to do it?
Someone please explain, what's wrong in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need a little bit of change in your code
Change this *str[start++] to (*str).at(start++)

```
  void reverse(string* str, int size)
    {
    
        int start = 0;
        int end = size - 1;
    
        while(start < end)
        {
           swap((*str).at(start++),(*str).at(end--));
        }
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
        
        string str = "Something";
        
        reverse(&str, str.length());
    
        cout << "Reversed string: " << str << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: But why? Isn't *str[start++] similar to *(str).at(start++)? If no then please tell me the difference

Comment: You are mixing up char* which is a pointer to a character and string* which is a pointer to a string object which needs dereferencing to access its characters

Comment: Um, you **know** that `start` and `end` are valid offsets into the string object, so there is no need to check them. Just use `swap((*str)[start++], (*str)[end--]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple fix. You don't need to change anything except a few lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>


void reverse( std::string* str ) // no need to pass size to this function
{

    int start = 0;
    int end = str->length() - 1; // get the length of str like this

    char* ptrToCharArray =  const_cast<char*>( str->c_str() ); // gets the pointer to str's internal buffer

    while ( start < end )
    {
        std::swap( ptrToCharArray[start++], ptrToCharArray[end--] ); // no need to use * operator anymore
    }
}


int main()
{
    
    std::string str = "Something";
    
    reverse( &str );

    std::cout << "Reversed string: " << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Reversed string: gnihtemoS
```

Hopefully, this helps you.

Comment: Why can’t you just use str->length()-1?

Comment: @Andrew Truckle Fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is **no need** to pass the size of the string as an argument to the function. You can use the member function `std::string::size` for that purpose as shown below:

**Version 1**: Passing pointer to string as argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void reverse(std::string *str)
{
    
    int n=(*str).size()-1;//dereference the pointer and use size member function on the resulting string object
  for(int i=0;i<((*str).size()/2);i++){
    //Using the swap method to switch values at each index
    std::swap((*str).at(i),(*str).at(n)); //note this can also be written as std::swap((*str)[i],(*str)[n]);
    n = n-1;

  }
}
int main()
{
    std::string myString = "myString";
    reverse(&myString);
    
    std::cout<<"Reversed string is: "<<myString<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In version 1, `*(str)` gives us a `std::string` type object. Next we call `size` member function on this `std::string` object. Similarly we can call the `std::string::at` member function on this `std::string` object.

**Version 2**: Passing reference to string as argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void reverse( std::string &str)
{
    
    int n=str.size()-1;
    for(int i=0;i<(str.size()/2);i++){
    //Using the swap method to switch values at each index
    std::swap(str.at(i),str.at(n));
    n = n-1;

  }
}
int main()
{
    std::string myString = "myString";
    reverse(myString);
    
    std::cout<<"Reversed string is: "<<myString<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you are dereferencing str pointer then using 'at' function?  is'nt 'str' points the address of first character of str?

Comment: @AdinathKolhapure When we write `*(str)` we dereference the pointer `str` and get a `std::string` object as a result. Next we call `size` member function on this `std::string` object and similarly we can also use `std::string::at` member function on the same `std::string` object. We need to dereference the pointer named `str` first so that we can access the underlying `std::string` object's individual characters either by using `at` or `operator[]`. I have used `at` but we can also use `operator[]` .

Comment: Re: "we can also use `operator[]`" -- that should be "we **should** use `operator[]`". There's no need to check the index values, because they are known to be correct.

Comment: @PeteBecker In this case yes `operator[]` should be preferred since there is no danger of going/accessing out of bounds and so no danger of UB. I used it in this particular example because the OP seems to be new to C++ and so might not be familiar with UB(same as many beginners) and using `at` safeguard against it so he/she might as well get familiar(if not already) with `at` member function.